# Possible bug in Next tag badge

Tags: support, tags, tag-badges, badge-progress

I just was navigate in users profile until I found the profile of [Juan Carlos Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7694740/juan-carlos-mendoza?tab=topactivity). I notice that the next badge is the silver [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) badge, but the score is less than 100. Shouldn't the next badge be **Bronze** and not a **Silver**?

[image: Next badge]

Any explanation?

Comment: Bronze involves *"Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the tag"*. One presumes that there may have been some reductions due to downvotes or answer removals. which have dropped this below 100. Badges aren't removed once earned IIRC....or it's **caching**...it's nearly always caching.

Comment: @Paulie_D *normal* badges aren't normally removed, but tag badges can be if you don't meet the requirements.

Comment: this is correct @Paulie_D if we notice in https://stackoverflow.com/users/7694740/juan-carlos-mendoza?tab=reputation his reputation get a Voting corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is:

- They earned the bronze [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag badge.
- Since it was then available, they then started tracking the *silver* [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag badge.
- They then *lost* the bronze badge. Which *can* happen with tag badges if you no longer meet the requirements.
- Nothing forced that window to switch to the bronze version.

Comment: I agree with you Stephen i think it a problem of cache